# Qt - QScrollArea Background also Behind Scroll Bars

Tags: qt

Attempting to add a background to a QScrollArea with the following:

```
scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);
scrollArea->setObjectName("scrollArea");

scrollWidget = new QWidget(scrollArea);
scrollWidget->setObjectName("scrollWidget");
scrollArea->setWidget(scrollWidget);

scrollArea->setStyleSheet(QString()
    + "#scrollArea { "
        + "border: none; "
        + "background: url(" + background + "); "
        + "background-attachment: fixed; "
        + "background-position: top center; "
    + "} #scrollWidget { background: transparent; } "
);
```

This works fine except the background of the scroll area is behind the scroll bars as well:

[image]

Is there a way to have the scrollbars use the background from the window behind the scroll area or another way to have them use their natural background?

Comment: Try: `scrollArea->setViewport(scrollWidget);` and apply styleSheet to widget. Is it work properly?

Comment: Calling setViewport() causes the widget to no longer scroll inside the scroll area. After compiling on Windows and Ubuntu (unity), it seems this is just a KDE/oxygen issue. Is there anyway to instruct the oxygen theme to not use transparent scroll bars?